# Iron Man anime movie featuring the Punisher, Hawkeye and Black Widow

Tags: story-identification, marvel, movie, anime, iron-man

I was recently on a cruise to Mexico and one of the shows on the TV was an Iron Man anime movie. It had the Punisher, Hawkeye, and Black Widow. The language was most likely Japanese and I had no captions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Iron Man: Rise of Technovore*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2654124/) (2013).

From IMDb:

> Billionaire Tony Stark, in his Iron Man armor, prevents an attack from a mysterious new foe, but innocent bystanders are killed, including his best friend War Machine, Lt. Colonel James Rhodes. Detained for questioning by S.H.I.E.L.D., Iron Man escapes, determined to find the mastermind behind the attack. Pursued by Black Widow and Hawkeye, Iron Man enlists the help of the ruthless vigilante The Punisher. But can the Armored Avenger handle what he finds when he catches the person responsible and is forced to face his deadliest weapon, a biotechnology called Technovore that could wipe out all life on the planet?

Comment: Yeah that was it, thanks

Comment: Rhodey dies? God damn it.

Answer (score 4):

The movie is **[Avengers Confidential: Black Widow & Punisher](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3482378/)** (2014).

From IMDb:

> After interfering with a top secret mission, THE PUNISHER is taken into custody by S.H.I.E.L.D. AGENT and AVENGER, BLACK WIDOW. At the orders of Director Nick Fury, Punisher and Black Widow are sent on a mission to stop LEVIATHAN, a global terrorist organization, that plans to sell stolen S.H.I.E.L.D. technology to the highest bidder. Now, the vigilante and spy must work together to prevent this technology from falling into the wrong hands. The fate of the world, and of the AVENGERS, hangs in the balance.